# binary > T does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Tags: c++, c++11

I am implementing a generic doubly linked list and am getting an error due to the **> and <** operators. Can anyone help me out?

**Note: I am not allowed to use any STL functions**

```
typename SortedList<T>::iterator SortedList<T>::insert(const T& data) {
    iterator it = begin();

    if (head_->next_ == tail_) {
        Node* newNode = new Node(data, tail_, head_);
        head_->next_ = newNode;
        tail_->prev_ = newNode;
        it.curr_ = newNode;
        ++size_;
        return it;
    }
    else {
        while (it != end()) {
            if ((*it < data) && (*it > data || it.curr_->next_ == tail_)) { // this line is giving me error
                Node* newNode = new Node(data, it.curr_->next_, it.curr_);
                it.curr_->next_->prev_ = newNode;
                it.curr_->next_ = newNode;
                it.curr_ = newNode;
                ++size_;
                return it;
            }
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `T` is not less-than or greater-than comparable.

Comment: Change `(*it > data || it.curr_->next_ == tail_)` to `((*it > data) || it.curr_->next_ == tail_)`

Comment: I did change it, but still gives me the same error. It doesn't throw any error when using < operator but just throws error for '>' @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @eerorika How can I fix it? I need to insert in a sorted way

Comment: What is `iterator` and more specially `iterator::operator*` ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like T is not less-than or greater-than comparable.

> How can I fix it?

1. Either make `T` comparable
2. or use a comparison object to compare the elements, just like the standard sorted containers do.

> how do I make T less-than and greater-than comparable?

If for example you've used the class `foo` as `T` to instantiate your template, then you ǹeed to make `foo` comparable.

This can be achieved by defining `bool operator<()(const foo&,const foo&)` to make it less-than comparable and `bool operator>()(const foo&,const foo&)` to make it greater-than comparable. Note that those functions should probably need to implement a strict weak ordering relation in order for your algorithm to work correctly.

Furthermore, you can use `b < a` instead of `a > b` in your algorithm so that only one direction of comparability is required.

> This is a generic doubly linked list so it should work for all data types right?

Not all types are comparable. Your function compares objects of the type so no: Your template doesn't work for all data types. It works only for those data types that are comparable.

If you were to use a comparison object, then your linked list could also work for non-comparable types for which a comparison object can be written.

> Can you explain me how to make comparion object?

Let us use the class `foo` as an example. You can make a comparison object for this class by writing a class (let us call it `Comp`) which overloads the following function call operator:

```
bool Comp::operator()(const foo&, const foo&) const
```

As with making `foo` comparable, this function also has to implement a strict weak ordering relation. Instance of such class is a comparison object. A lambda can suffice.

You should use a template argument in your list template to let the user of the template provide a comparison object that can compare the objects of type `T`. Store the object as a member of the list, and only use the comparison object to compare elements of the list instead of the relational operators.

Comment: I cannot use comparison objects and how do I make T less-than and greater-than comparable? This is a generic doubly linked list so it should work for all data types right?

Comment: Can you explain me how to make comparion object? @eerorika